# I Want to extract time from a string

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

String Example:

```
DH      SG 136      BOM      (20:15)       (22:20)      DEL  FLT     SG 11       DEL      (08:55)       (12:50)      DXB  FLT     SG 14       DXB      (14:00)       (16:55)      BOM
```

My Query is:

```
 select
 right (substring(previousdata,0,charindex(':',previousdata)+1),3)+
 left(substring(previousdata,charindex(':',previousdata)+1, len(previousdata)),2) as TimeSt,
  PreviousData from com.NOTIFICATIONHISTORY
```

the problem is it is also extracting non numeric values back  and forth semicolon :
i want only time.. very first 'time' mentioned in string

Comment: DH: SG 282 MAA-AMD 12:13 28-Nov-2013   14:38 28-Nov-2013, FLT :SG 345 AMD-PNQ 21:34 22:55, FLT :SG 345 PNQ-BLR 23:39 01:05. this string returns wrong value

Comment: You should provide sample data *and desired results*.  Your explanation is not clear.

Comment: i just need 2 digits before the semicolon and 2 digits after the semicolon

Comment: i need result as 12:15. please note that the string is very fishy. there are other semicilons in the starting of the string that have alphabets before and after it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like the timestamps in the string have leading zeroes (so 01:15, not 1:15) and something like the following should work:

```
select SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', X), 5)
```

Test:

```
select
SUBSTRING(X, PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]%', X), 5)
, X
from
(select 
 'DH      SG 136      BOM      (20:15)       (22:20)      DEL  FLT     SG 11       DEL      (08:55)       (12:50)      DXB  FLT     SG 14       DXB      (14:00)       (16:55)      BOM  
 ' AS x UNION SELECT 
 'DH: SG 282 MAA-AMD 12:13 28-Nov-2013 14:38 28-Nov-2013, FLT :SG 345 AMD-PNQ 21:34 22:55, FLT :SG 345 PNQ-BLR 23:39 01:05
 ' AS x ) data
```

Result:

```
(No column name)    X
20:15   DH      SG 136      BOM      (20:15)       (22:20)      DEL  FLT     SG 11       DEL      (08:55)       (12:50)      DXB  FLT     SG 14       DXB      (14:00)       (16:55)      BOM     
12:13   DH: SG 282 MAA-AMD 12:13 28-Nov-2013 14:38 28-Nov-2013, FLT :SG 345 AMD-PNQ 21:34 22:55, FLT :SG 345 PNQ-BLR 23:39 01:05
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you were making this requirement more complex than it needs to be.  Just take the first five characters after the first occurrence of `(`:

```sql
SELECT SUBSTRING(col, CHARINDEX('(', col) + 1, 5)
FROM yourTable;
```

### Demo

Comment: Just to add that if you you can't rely on the first occurrence of ( but can rely on the first occurence of : then it's pretty much the same just change the +1 to -2

Comment: @Bee_Riii But then it becomes a cat and mouse game, because perhaps `:` appears first in some other context than a time `:-)`

Comment: Agreed.  I was pointing out that your simplification is easily modified if their anchor is 
   : 
which could be implied for the users use of it in their query.